# Finding elementary matrices to complete a set of matrix equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image]

I have $89\%$ of the values correct but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong exactly.

For the first ones, the first row is being multiplied by $2$ and then multiplied by $\frac12$, so I multiplied the identity matrix's first row by those amounts.

For the second ones, the second and third row are switched for both so I switched the second and third row of the identity matrix for both as well.

For the third ones, the first row is being added to $4$ times the second row and $-4$ times the second row. So I switched the the first and second row of the identity matrix and multiplied it by $4$ and $-4$ respectively. I have a feeling that this is where I'm going wrong but I'm not sure why.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is with the third one (both parts)

For the first part:

If $4$ times the second row is added to the first row, perform this operation on the identity matrix would give you

$$\begin{bmatrix} \color{red}1 & 4 & 0  \\ \color{red}0 & \color{red}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Notice the determinant of this elementary operation is $1$.

Try to fix the case when $-4$ times the second row is added to the first row.